# How do I validate my multiple linear regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, cross-validation, validation

I have split my data into two parts. I have used my 80% data to build a multiple regression linear model. Now I want to test it using my rest 20% data. What tools on Minitab do I have to make this checking process?

Edit: I think I can use PRESS statistic. My PRESS for 80% data was 6000 and now based on this model I have calculated the PRESS for 20% data, it is 1000. Now, should I compare 6000 with 1000  or 6000 with 5 times 1000, ie 5000?

Comment: Oh. I have one response with more than one predictors.

Answer (score 8):

Note that the [predicted residual sum of squares, PRESS,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic) is got by jack-knifing the sample: there's no sense in calculating it for training & test sets. Calculate it for a model fitted to the whole sample (& compare it to the RSS to assess the amount of over-fitting). For ordinary least-squares regression there's an analytic solution:

$$\sum_i \left(\frac{e_i}{1-h_{ii}}\right)^2$$

where $e_i$ is the $i$th residual & $h_{ii}$ its leverage—from the diagonal of the hat matrix

$$H=X(X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1}X^\mathrm{T}$$

(where $X$ is the design matrix).

In general cross-validation & bootstrap validation are preferable to splitting a sample into training & test sets: you don't lose precision in the estimates as when fitting on a smaller training set, & the performance measure on the test set will be less variable. How preferable depends on sample size.

Comment: so you are saying that it is possible to use 100% of the data on a number of models, and then use a bootstrap/cross-validate method to rate the best model using some sort of fit statistic.  Is that right?

Comment: @EngrStudent: I had in mind the simpler situation of the OP's question, where you fit one model (to the whole sample) & then estimate the predictive performance of the fitting procedure through cross-validation or bootstrap validation. You certainly can evaluate a model selection procedure in the same way, but need to make sure you include the whole selection procedure in each cross-validation fold or bootstrap iteration. So `validation(selection + fitting)`, not `selection + validation(fitting)`.

Comment: That sounds great.  I have always disliked the separation of a sample into training and validation because I felt that I was giving up quality of fit.  Can you point to a paper or tutorial that is a good step-by-step walkthrough of this approach?

Comment: [Hastie et al. (2009), *The Elements of Statistical Learning*, Ch.7](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/]) for what it is; [Harrell (2001), *Regression Modelling Strategies*](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RmS) for where it fits in.

Comment: Recalculate the hat matrix for each sample .. ?  Seems large amount of calculations.

Comment: @javadba: Calculate the hat matrix once, for *the* sample, as an alternative to re-sampling, re-fitting, & calculating RSS many times.

Answer (score 7):

You may use Root Mean Squared Error [(RMSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) which is a measurement of accuracy between two set of values.

Use your model of type $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots + \beta_nX_n$ calibrated from your 80% dataset, on the independent variables (IV) of your another 20% dataset (validation dataset).

In R use `rmse` function from `hydroGOF` package.

Example:

```
# create an object with dependent variable (DV) values from the validation dataset.
dv_observed = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

# use the multiple linear regression model (derived from the calibration dataset) to predict DV values as from validation dataset IV values. Then, create another object.
dv_predicted = c(1,3,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10)

require(hydroGOF)
rmse(dv_observed,dv_predicted)
[1] 0.4472136
```

RMSE output measurement unit is the same of your data (e.g. if DV is weight in pounds, RMSE will be pounds too).